# UIImageVIew crop Image center according to ImageView size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a UIImageView that will have a fixed size (i'm not using auto layout) and content image inside it will be centred.

The problem is that the image is big, and it enlarge my UIImageView - which corrupt the view i'm showing, so my only option is to Scale To Fit which make my image look bad.

Is it possible to do that with AutoLayout ?

Comment: 320X78 (it's a kind of a cover photo) and i'm loading images that are larger that that. i just want to crop the center of the image to that size, without change the size of the imageview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AHHH - just use "center" mode on that selector.

And set **CLIP SUBVIEWS** checkbox.

Let us know if that fixes it.

---

For 2015 onwards, it's worth noting that there is no reason at all not to use autolayout.

Comment: can't believe i've missed that

Comment: It took me like 12 years to figure that out  :)